# PHP Shorten GET URL

Tags: php, url, get

A web site I've been working on is almost entirely form inputs that links back to itself.  I want the user to be able to bookmark the specific settings and have them automatically there when he visits.  The problem is this results in a very long URL (almost 500 characters).  Is there any way I can shorten the GET URL?

Most of the variables are a simple on/off switch so I don't need to keep track of a lot of detail.

Comment: Who knows? You haven't shown us the URL you want to shorten.

Comment: Do you need the GET variables at all? Otherwise you can do some string manipulations using $_SERVER variables.

Comment: Save *long* URL in database and map it with *short* URL, redirect on request. Or just load *GET* data from database.

Answer (score 0):

you can use http://yourls.org - a set of php scripts that enable you to track short urls, like the commercial bit.ly

Comment: This is not an answer, more of a comment.

Comment: @webarto if you read the "correct use of comments" for stackoverflow you would find that this is fine to be an answer and also your comment on the actual question is more of an answer than comment

Answer (score 0):

You're nowhere near the [limit of URL length](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/417142/what-is-the-maximum-length-of-a-url-in-different-browsers) (around 2000 as of this writing).

However, you should really cookie/session this information or -- if they **must** be able to easily switch to a different browser/machine -- roll your own URL shortener (just create a unique key that is appended to every request and get the variables associated with that key from a database).